# Merge colors using javascript

Tags: javascript

Let say I have some element with background and foreground colors.
Let say there could be both colors specified in different formats (any that could be specified in style attribute) like background = 'white' or 'transparent', foreground = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'.
What is simplest way to merge these colors using pure javascript to get result like rgb(128, 128, 128)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe setting `opacity` CSS attribute to half (`0.5`) of the element on the front will get you there.

Alternatively, if you are using jQuery and you really want to get this into JavaScript, you can get both colors with jQuery's [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/), which returns something like `rgb(0,0,0)`, then make averages of each base color (red, green, blue) and set the resulting value to whatever you need with the same directive ([`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)).

Did it help?

Comment: +1 - you should set both opacities to .5, otherwise the color shown will be darker than an actual merger of the two

Comment: Agreed, this is much simpler than my answer and should work for your purposes.

Comment: @trey I do not agree (btw. thanks for the upvote). I have made a benchmark which shows me, that if I set opacity of both first and second element to .5 it actually is lighter, but lighter also than the color we want to get (setting first element opacity did work for me). Do you have some example proving otherwise? If you do, I will correct my answer.

Comment: .css() could return string 'transparent' as a result

Comment: in my experience with graphics, two overlapping colors both set at 50% opacity they create a different color section that has a 100% opacity it follows that the more saturated the merging area is, the further off from the actual blended color it will be, and visa versa

Comment: but.... I think you're right, on the html canvas the same rule doesn't seem to apply:)

Comment: the closes to my need and simplest approach seems to be your variant with opacity, thanks.

Comment: @Mykhaylo No problem :) @trey I know there is sometimes lack of logic in how web technologies in general work ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just cuz i like writing complicated scripts....

```
<span style="background-color:black; color:#fff";>Hi</span>
```

JS:

```
function getColorVals(color) {
    color = color.replace("rgb", "").replace("(", "").replace(")", "");
    return color.split(",");
}
var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
var color1 = window.getComputedStyle(span).backgroundColor; //window.getComputedStyle ensures getting back rgb
var color2 = window.getComputedStyle(span).color;
var color1Vals = getColorVals(color1);
var color2Vals = getColorVals(color2);
var newColorVal = "rgb(";
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    newColorVal += Math.round((Math.abs(color1Vals[i] - color2Vals[i]) / 2));
    if(i<2) newColorVal += ",";
} 
newColorVal += ")";
alert(newColorVal);
```

...you could easily work the opacity in there as well.

### EDIT:

popped in Math.round in the color val calculation to fix decimals and such.

Comment: window.getComputedStyle(span).backgroundColor could return string 'transparent' as a result

Comment: @Mykhaylo Adamovych yeah, i didn't put in support for transparency/opacity. You could easily catch "transparent" and replace it with something else, or work in `rgba` instead of `rgb` (in which case the rgba value for transparent would be "rgba(0,0,0,0)"

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [rbgcolor.js](http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/).  It "accepts a string and tries to figure out a valid color out of it".  That is, you could simply look at the CSS color attribute on an element, feed it through this JS, and get the RGB values.  Once you have the RGB values, simply take the average of each channel to create your new color.

You may have to do some finessing if the color of your element is inherited.  e.g., if your element doesn't have a specified color property, check it's parent, all the way up the DOM.